# Modify <video> behaviour for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

The blow jQuery is being used to create simple controls for a  element. However, if I have multiple  tags on a single page, the script effects all of them, rather than just the one clicked.

How can I modify the below to only effect that particular instance?

Thanks

```
    // Play/Pause button functionality
    // On click
    $('.video .icon').click(function() {
        if ($('.video video').hasClass('is-playing')) {
            // Add class to style controls
            $('.video video').removeClass().addClass('is-paused');
            // Pause video
            $('.video video')[0].pause();
        } else {
            // Add class to style controls
            $('.video video').removeClass().addClass('is-playing');
            // Play video
            $('.video video')[0].play();
        }
        return false;
    });
    // On touchstart
    $('.video .icon').on('touchstart', function() {
        $('.video video')[0].play();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Show us your HTML structure

Comment: simply replace `$('.video video')` with `$(this).parents('.video').find('video')`

Comment: Thanks @slash197 - perfect, works well! Is there a way to pause all other video elements when one starts playing, to avoid having multiple videos playing at any one time?

If you want to convert this comment into an answer I'll happily accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to target ONLY the element currently being interacted with, we can simply replace `$('.video video')` with `$(this).parent().find('video')`. In effect, this looks for the parent of `.icon`, and then within this search for any `<video>` elements.

```
// Play/Pause button functionality
// On click
$('.video .icon').click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().find('video').hasClass('is-playing')) {
        // Add class to style controls
        $(this).parent().find('video').removeClass().addClass('is-paused');
        // Pause video
        $(this).parent().find('video')[0].pause();
    } else {
        // Add class to style controls
        $(this).parent().find('video').removeClass().addClass('is-playing');
        // Play video
        $(this).parent().find('video')[0].play();
    }
    return false;
});
// On touchstart
$('.video .icon').on('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('video')[0].play();
    return false;
});
```